# What does @protocol mean?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Looking at Apples header file NSView.h

I see this line

```
@protocol NSDraggingSource;
```

Later I see

```
@interface NSView : NSResponder <..., NSDraggingDestination,...>
```

So what protocols does the NSView conform to?

Comment: the first line is a forward declaration. it just tells the compiler, that there is a protocol called NSDraggingSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two completely different issues:

- The `@protocol` is simply a "forward declaration" of a protocol called `NSDraggingSource`. This effectively says "there exists a protocol called `NSDraggingSource` and should be accepted syntactically as a protocol reference." The requirements of the protocol are unknown until you come across the actual protocol definition, though.

  These forward declarations are often used when you want to specify that a property or method parameter must conform to a protocol, but at this point you aren't concerned about what the protocol requirements are. The protocol definition must be defined by the time you get to the `@implementation` of these methods and properties, but at the point of the `@interface` we merely need to know that a protocol of that name exists.
- You ask why they didn't just add `NSDraggingSource` to the list of protocols to which `NSView` conforms. The mere presence of the `@protocol` forward declaration has nothing to do with whether `NSView` conforms or not.

  In this case, it's not `NSView` that conforms to this protocol, but rather the `source` parameter to one of `NSView`'s methods, namely [`beginDraggingSessionWithItems`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483791-begindraggingsessionwithitems?language=occ). So, in the `@interface` we need to know that a protocol of that name exists, but we won't worry about the specific requirements of that protocol until we get to the `@implementation`.